# 2's complement binary numbers to decimal (16 bit)

Tags: binary

For 2's complement of 0011100111010011 to decimal I got 14803. However someone told me this is incorrect, but couldn't tell me exactly why. Can someone point me in the right direction or clarify if I have this correct?

Comment: Seems to be correct.

Comment: Thank you. I've searching all over and everything points to it being correct.